# Вставка IMG в DIV contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Хочу вставить `IMG` смайлик в редактируемый `DIV` с учётом положения курсора, используя чистый JS (без jquery). В ходе полуторачасового поиска в интернете, так и не смог найти нормальный пример. Неужели это такая невыполнимая задача?

У меня есть в бэкапах рабочий пример, но он исключительно для `TEXTAREA`. К редактируемому блоку с атрибутом `contenteditable` он не подходит.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит `с учётом положения курсора`?

Comment: @diraria а что это еще может значить?)

Comment: @diraria, это значит, что `IMG` вставляется ровно туда, где установлен курсор.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Получаем выделение с помощью метода [`Window::getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)
- Проверяем, выделено ли что-нибудь с помощью свойства [`Selection::rangeCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Selection/rangeCount)
- Получаем первый диапазон выделения с помощью метода [`Selection::getRangeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt)
- Вставляем изображение в конец диапаозона с помощью метода [`Range::insertNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode)
- [Статья по теме на learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection)

```js
let editable = document.getElementById('editable');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mousedown', onclick);

function onclick(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // чтобы #editable не терял фокус
  insertImage();
}

function insertImage() {
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = "http://placehold.it/20x20";
  selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount === 0 /* нет выделения */ ||
    // выделение лежит не в #conteneditable
    !editable.contains(selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer)) {
    // вставляем в конец элемента #editable
    editable.appendChild(image);
  } else {
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    // сжимаем range в его правый конец
    range.collapse(false);
    // вставляем картинку
    range.insertNode(image);

    // делаем, чтобы курсор был после вставленной картинки
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    range.setStartAfter(image);
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```css
#editable {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<button>Добавить картинку</button>
<div id="editable" contenteditable>Редактируемый элемент</div>
```

Comment: не плохо было бы еще и фокус сохранять

Comment: @Cheg, да, обновил